# New ipod on Rhythmbox

Tags: ipod

[image][image]I have been using Rhythmbox as a library for my original ipod classic that does not work anymore, therefore i bought a custom made ipod and connected it to Rhythmox and transferred the whole library to my new ipod. But the ipod does not recognize the files as music files but as other files, which means that my music is not accessible. What can i do?

Comment: What format are the files in?

Comment: What is a "custom made ipod"?

Comment: Well, ipods are not produced any more by apple. Some vendors offer ipods via etsy, where i bought mine, according to self chosen specifications (256 GB storage). The files are mosty mp3 oder m4a.

Comment: Somebody here https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/vb1kit/syncing_an_ipod_classic_with_rhythmbox/ was saying that they used `gtkpod` instead of `rhythmbox` to fix their issue.  `sudo apt install gtkpod`